# pdf que contenta un jpanel plantilla y se agregue al mismo cada vez que se recorra y se cambia la información

Tags: java

Como puedo hacer un pdf de un jpanel el cual funciona como la plantilla de una factura y necesito que se agregue al mismo pdf, pero solo se guarda uno y se imprime.

esta es la forma que estoy usando para hacerlo.

```
Toolkit tk = pnlFactura.getToolkit();
                PrintJob pj = tk.getPrintJob(this, null, null);
                Graphics g = pj.getGraphics();
                pnlFactura.print(g);
                g.dispose();
                pj.end();
```

[image: a plantilla hecha en un jpanel, el cual mando a imprimir]

Comment: osea que quieres que cada que tus datos cambien en la base de datos se actualice el pdf?

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Answer (score 0):

Quiero que se pueda agregar el PDF de cada usuario en uno mismo, cuando realizó el recorrido por medio del ciclo for para guardar el jpanel en un pdf, se agregan individual, es decir genera un PDF para cada uno y no en uno solo, en el mismo archivo PDF.

Quiero que se guarden en un mismo PDF.